# Is there a height difference between a TextField and SecureField in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

[image]

I'm building a simple login screen and I noticed that when I change between a TextField and a SecureField my screen moves a little and I think it's because their heights are changing? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Here's the code:

```swift
struct LoginView: View {
    @State var username: String
    @State var password: String
    @State var showingPassword: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 15) {
                Text("Welcome")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .padding(.bottom)
                TextField("Username", text: $username)
                    .customTextField()
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color("charcoal"), lineWidth: 0.6))
                HStack {
                    if showingPassword {
                        TextField("Password", text: $password)
                            .customTextField()
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color("charcoal"), lineWidth: 0.6))
                            .border(.pink)
                        Image(systemName: "eye.slash")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                showingPassword.toggle()
                            }
                            .border(.pink)
                    } else {
                        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                            .customTextField()
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color("charcoal"), lineWidth: 0.6))
                            .border(.green)
                        Image(systemName: "eye")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                showingPassword.toggle()
                            }
                            .foregroundColor(Color("charcoal"))
                            .border(.green)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

and the modifier:

```swift
struct TextFieldModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.vertical, 12)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 0.6))
            .lineLimit(5)
    }
}

extension View {
    func customTextField() -> some View {
        modifier(TextFieldModifier())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is indeed a height difference. You can inspect it by using Xcode's UI inspector on a view as simple as:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("Username", text: $username)
        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
    }
}
```

On my simulator, the text field has height 22, and the secure field has height 21.

[image]

[image]

This difference in height is also visible in the picture in Apple's documentation page for [`SecureField`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/securefield). The picture is:

[image]

You can try opening the image up in Preview.app or similar and count the pixels (I did that!).

I'm not sure if this difference is intended or not.

Comment: This doesn't appear like purposeful adherence to any interface guideline at all. Very unfortunate that implementing a show/hide password toggle causes such jankiness in switching states, but hopefully Apple will address it.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed janky! I had the same problem and solved it by adding `.frame(height: 22)` to both fields, It's probably not needed on the `TextField`, but I decided to add it there, in the event that it get's rendered differently in some case.

Here's my full code snippet:

```
HStack {
    Group {
        if showPassword {
            TextField("Password",
                        text: $password,
                        prompt: Text("Password"))
            .frame(height: 22)
        } else {
            SecureField("Password",
                        text: $password,
                        prompt: Text("Password"))
            .frame(height: 22)
        }
    }
    .padding(10)

    Button {
        showPassword.toggle()
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: showPassword ? "eye.slash" : "eye")
            .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```